# Can't create splitter with Split.js

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, splitter, split.js

i have:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split.js/dist/split.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        import Split from 'split.min.js'
        Split(['#split-0', '#split-1'],
            {
                direction: 'vertical'
            });
    });
</script>
```

So, i have an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Error referencing to  `import Split from 'split.js'`
What should i do? Code was copied from official site.

Comment: remove the import statement it should work, import statement what you have written will look for the package in node_modules, so it needs to be installed using yarn or npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the UMD build of script, as you do in your example by referencing the URL `https://unpkg.com/split.js/dist/split.min.js`, the Split object is **not** exposed as a JavaScript module that can be accessed through an import statement.

Instead, it will be available as a global variable, which you can access through `window.Split` or simply `Split`.

This should work:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split.js/dist/split.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Split(['#split-0', '#split-1'],
            {
                direction: 'vertical'
            });
    }); 
</script>
```